# Which is the correlation between an ORDER and the USER who bought in WooCommerce/WordPress database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to know if a user has bought a WooCommerce product. And if is it possible how many order he did.

So I checked in the WordPress database, and find the "wp_woocommerce_order_items" table.

here I can find these data
[image]

The order_item_id field is used to join this table with the products meta. I don't find the reason for the order_id.

And I can't understand how I can find the user who made the order.

[image]

As you can see in the second picture (wp_usermeta table) I don't have no one field common with the order table.

So which is the common filed to join this 2 table?

I need only the field name that contain this info/value.

Virtual hugs for those who help me!

Comment: Do you have another table that link user and order ? Can you at least show us a list of your tables ?

Comment: Thank you, I post my own answer if you still curious! :)

Answer (score 3):

I just found the solutions for my own question! Thanks to everyone who answer me, you all helped me find the solution!

I didn't know how WooCommerce save the order.

I just discover that the orders are saved using a post_type called shop_order.

So basically I find the user ID in the shop_order metas in wp_postmeta!

Here some screen with the SQL queries I did:

**SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'**

[image]

**SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id = 1949**

[image]

Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$customer_orders = get_posts( 
    array(
        'numberposts' => $order_count,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
    )
);
```

This is basically from the template file `my-orders`. (woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php). You can customize this code for your requirement. This gets you orders for the customer. You will need to change `get_current_user_id()` with the desired customers user id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this helped me! I didn't know how WooCommerce save the order. 

Now I just discover that the orders are saved using a post_type called shop_order. So basically I find the user ID in the shop_order metas in wp_postmeta!